# CareKit and ResearchKit conflict

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, researchkit, carekit

I have a problem with types of results form surveys. 
If I use CareKit / HealthKit surveys, everything is fine, when I want to mix it with ResearchKit surveys - I have error in method below:

```
func buildCarePlanResultFrom(taskResult: ORKTaskResult) -> OCKCarePlanEventResult {
    guard let firstResult = taskResult.firstResult as? ORKStepResult,
        let stepResult = firstResult.results?.first else {
            fatalError("Unexepected task results")
    }
    if let numericResult = stepResult as? ORKNumericQuestionResult,
        let answer = numericResult.numericAnswer {
        return OCKCarePlanEventResult(valueString: answer.stringValue, unitString: numericResult.unit, userInfo: nil)
    } else {

    }

    fatalError("Unexpected task result type")
}
```

Which is - I think - because I cannot make a OCKCarePlanEventResult object [answer and numericResult are both nil].

I update symptoms tracker in extension below:

```
extension TabBarViewController: ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate {
func taskViewController(_ taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWith
    reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: Error?) {
    defer {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    guard reason == .completed else { return }
    guard let symptomTrackerViewController = symptomTrackerViewController,
        let event = symptomTrackerViewController.lastSelectedAssessmentEvent else { return }
    symptomTrackerViewController.progressRingTintColor = .lightGreen
    symptomTrackerViewController.delegate = self
    let carePlanResult = carePlanStoreManager.buildCarePlanResultFrom(taskResult: taskViewController.result)
    carePlanStoreManager.store.update(event, with: carePlanResult, state: .completed) {
        success, _, error in
        if !success {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}}
```

Any suggestions how convert type of results from ResearchKit to CareKit or other solution to update the view?

May, this will be helpful, example of task:

```
    let sleepHoursSurveyActivity = OCKCarePlanActivity.assessment(
        withIdentifier: ActivityIdentifier.sleepHours.rawValue,
        groupIdentifier: nil,
        title: "Sleep Hours",
        text: nil,
        tintColor: .darkGreen,
        resultResettable: true,
        schedule: dailyScheduleRepeating(occurencesPerDay: 1),
        userInfo: ["ORKTask" : AssessmentTaskFactory.sleepHoursSurveyAssessmentTask()])

static func sleepHoursSurveyAssessmentTask() -> ORKTask {
    var steps = [ORKQuestionStep]()
    let question = NSLocalizedString("How many hours did you sleep?", comment: "")
    let textChoices = [
        ORKTextChoice(text: "1-3", value: "1-3" as NSString),
        ORKTextChoice(text: "4-5", value: "4-5" as NSString),
        ORKTextChoice(text: "6-7", value: "6-7" as NSString),
        ORKTextChoice(text: "8", value: "8" as NSString),
        ORKTextChoice(text: "more than 8", value: "more than 8" as NSString)
        ]

    let questAnswerFormat: ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat = ORKAnswerFormat.choiceAnswerFormat(with: .singleChoice, textChoices: textChoices)
    let sleepHoursSurvaySteps = ORKQuestionStep(identifier: "sleepHours", title: question, answer: questAnswerFormat)
    sleepHoursSurvaySteps.isOptional = false
    steps += [sleepHoursSurvaySteps]

    return ORKOrderedTask(identifier: "sleepHoursSurveyTask", steps: [sleepHoursSurvaySteps])
}
```

Comment: I do not know where is the problem, because firstResult and stepResult are perfectly fine for HK, CR and RK, all have the same types. And suddenly numericResult and answer are nil in RK. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `sleepHoursSurveyAssessmentTask` which returns a task doesn't have a numeric answer format. You are using an `ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat` which you can extract from `ORKTaskResult` using `ORKChoiceQuestionResult`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the format, and problem is still the same.